# Why are the properties for Audit Policy Disabled?

Tags: windows-xp, security

=I am logged in as an Administrator on my machine and when I check Local Security Settings -> Audit Policy -> Audit Account logon events I click on "Properties" and try to turn it off for "Success" and "Faiulre" but the checkboxes are disabled. Anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Is your machine a member of a domain?  If so, then Group Policy may be overriding those settings.

Comment: Yes it is. Do you know how I can view/change the Group Policy?

Comment: If it's being overridden by a higher level group policy, someone with appropriate domain permissions will need create an exception for your machine.  You'll want to talk to whoever administers your domain.